# Proving that $\bigotimes_{i=1}^n \cal{B}_{X_i} = \cal{B}_{X}$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

**Theorem**: Given separable metric spaces $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and $X=\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$, where $X$ has the product metric $d(f,g)=\sqrt{d_1 (f(1),g(1))^2 +\cdots + d_n (f(n),g(n))^2}$. Then $\bigotimes_{i=1}^n \cal{B}_{X_i} = \cal{B}_{X}$. Where $\cal{B}_X$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X$.

Folland proves this on page 23. And I understand his proof except for the line where he says that balls of radius $r$ in $X$ are products of balls of radius $r$ in the $X_i$'s. It seems like he's saying that $B(f;r)=\prod_{i=1}^n B(f(i);r)$. But this isn't true, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ it would be saying that circles are same as squares. What is wrong here?

Comment: What does $\bigotimes_{i=1}^n \cal B_{X_i}$ stand for? The product $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: He probably means that balls of radius $r$ in $X$ *can be generated* by products of balls of radius $r$ in the $X_i$'s, which would be true in that case. You can take this union to be countable if you center those rectangles at rational coordinates (which is the same idea in a general separable metric space).

The equivalent in $\mathbb R^2$ of my version of the statement would be that you can write a ball in $\mathbb R^2$ as a union of squares centered at each point with small enough sides.